# Asp.net 2.0 and c# 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We use asp.net where I work and we are using c# as the language. Will c# 3.0 work with asp.net 2.0? Ive been trying to pick up some books on c#, but not sure which I should be buying, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET hasn't seen major changes since version 2.0 (a full list can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Versions)). Some large changes are coming near the end of this year with both ASP.NET 4.0, and .NET framework 4.0.

The language C#, however, has developed vastly over the years. In its current version (C# 3.0)  the language has lots of features which will benefit you. It can be used to target the latest version of the .NET framework (3.5), or any earlier version you choose.

I would recommend books on ASP.NET 2.0, C# 3.0, and the .NET framework 3.5.

Comment: Except there is no such thing as C# 3.5. It is still C# 3.

Comment: There is no such thing as C# 3.5 (see Jon Skeet's post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Comment: I think this debate just emphasises how confusing the versioning/naming has got!

Comment: @thedorko, just be sure to keep track of the three separate entities (the web framework, the language compiler, and the runtime framework), and you're golden :) Post corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, ASP.NET is a web application technology (as opposed to a language), and you can use any .NET language to back it. ASP.NET 2.0 and C# 3.0 play quite nicely together.

Answer (score 2):

You bet.

Here is a book I would highly recommend:

Beginning ASP.NET 2.0 with C#
[[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-ASP-NET-2-0-Wrox-Guides/dp/0470042583](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470042583)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470042583)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer to this question also answers your question:

[Upgrade to ASP.NET 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627/upgrade-to-asp-net-3-x)

Essentially, you set-up IIS to asp.net 2.0 for both 2.0 and 3.5 sites, as they both run on the same CLR.